# CSS - how do I float another div over another without overlapping

Tags: html, css

Hey I want to put that lower div box beside that upper box with details but when I try to position absolute it I goes down idk why (I made the parent div of all three divs as position rlative ) , how am I supposed to fix this or any other better way to do this .

Here is the screenshot -
http://www.findportugal.com/Untitled.png

Div Description

```
   #user_panel - div around all the other divs ie parent div
   #user_details - div with details on top
   #user_photos - div with photo heading
   #user_current - div at the lower part
```

CSS :

```
    #user_panel 
    { 
      color: white; 
      position: relative; 
    }
    #user_details 
    { 
      padding: 0 0 30px 0; 
    }
    #user_details table 
    { 
      padding: 30px 20px 10px 30px; 
      border: 1px solid grey; 
      margin: 0 60px 0 40px
    }
    #user_details table tbody tr td#right 
    { 
      padding: 0 0 0 100px; 
    }
    #users_title 
    { 
      padding: 20px 0 0 50px; 
    }

    div#user_photos 
    { 
       width: 850px; 
       height: 230px; 
       border: 1px solid grey; 
       margin: 50px 0 0 40px;
       padding: 0 0 20px 20px;  
    }

   #user_current 
   {
      border: 1px solid grey; 
      width: 320px; 
      position: absolute; 
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us some CSS and HTML to work with?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how to ask questions on SO... This is in the improper format. You must post code samples. Requesting that we visit a site is unacceptable.

Comment: `position:absolute` will cause the box to no longer affect the automatic height of its container, and if you give no X/Y coordinates it will go to the bottom of the content like that

Comment: Please provide us with code. It could be that you need to float issues that need to be cleared.

Comment: Im so sorry about this but is there a way I can fix this so that I could display that lower div beside the top one

Comment: The reason `position:absolute` is pushing the box down is because that is what float uses to push elements to one side or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a div OVER another div and you are saying it should NOT OVERLAP which is not possible, instead decrease the size of upper div, use `float: left;` and this will let the div below shift besides the floated div

Also don't forget to clear floats, or you'll spend other 2 hours thinking what the hell is going on with the element positions as well as background color

And if you want to use `position: absolute;` than the div will overlap, so in this case, use `position: relative;` for the container element and than use `position: absolute;` with `top right bottom left properties to set your element correctly`.

Don't forget `position: relative;` else your absolute div will run wild in your page

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to place that lower div box in the empty space to the right of the upper-left div box, and not actually overlapping the other box? If so, you would be better off using floats.

You haven't shown your html, so let's assume the upper-left box has an id of "details", the bottom box has an id of "current-pic", and the full-width box in the middle in your screenshot as an id of "photos". A starting point for building the layout would then be like the following.

EDITED: *Sorry, I wrote the answer before you updated your question with your HTML. The code is rewritten below to show the ids in your original html.*

The HTML could be:

```
<div id="user_details"></div>
<div id="user_current"></div>
<div id="user_photos"></div>
```

The basic layout CSS would be something like:

```
#user_details {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   /* other styling stuff like padding, etc. */
}
#user_current {
   float: right;
   width: 50%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   /* other styling stuff like padding, etc. */
}
#user_photos {
   clear: both;
}
```

This doesn't account for any of the content inside the boxes, or spacing between the boxes, but the `box-sizing` rule will help you to maintain your layout and build up margins, padding, and borders without them breaking it.